# CSS Standard Browsers vs. iPhone or mobile devices : two box models? trick example

Tags: iphone, css, model, floating

This should intrigue CSS specialists. Here is a situation where I experimented two different behaviors for the box model support :

On one side : 
All standard browsers (IE, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc., from IE7+, etc., and even Safari for iPad or iPhones with iOS6+)

On the other side :
Some mobile browsers (tested iPhone/iPod, and on Samsung Galaxy Ace (Android) devices).

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="floatright">Sidecontent Sidecontent Sidecontent Sidecontent Sidecontent Sidecontent Sidecontent Sidecontent Sidecontent Sidecontent </div>
    <div class="nofloat">Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
    background: yellow;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
}
.nofloat {
    background: pink;
    float: none;
    margin-right: 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.floatright {
    background: orange;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can test it here : http://jsfiddle.net/Kyk2P/1/

Now here is the story :

In standard browsers, the `.nofloat` element spans the full width of its parent, because it is not floated. The `.floatright` element floats "over" it on its right side and for this reason, pushes its content to the left. The property `overflow: hidden;` does one more trick: instead of having the text wrapping the floated element, it stays in a column on the left. The floated element technically only pushes the "content" of the `.nonfloat` container, not the container itself, which has the following result : no margin is therefore visible, as it is applied to the right of the .nofloat container which is actually "covered" by the floated element. This is the normal result one would expect.

On an iPod (iOS5) or Samsung Ace device, the result is different. It seems like the The `.nofloat` element only fills the room in the parent container that is left empty after the `.floatright` has been floated to the right. Result : the container itself finds a narrower context in which to apply its margins and wedges on the floated element. In this case, we get a margin between the content (in fact, the container...) and the floated element.

An image being better than words, here is what happens :

[image: Results in each cases]

My questions are :

1. Is this normal?
2. What way should the CSS rule be expressed so that we get the same result (preferably case #1) in both cases?

--- EDIT ---

Thanks to Angelin, I know now that iPhones with iOS6 get Case#1. However, iPhones with previous iOS and Android phones do get case#2. Nightmare!

Comment: I get case #1 on iPhone using your fiddle

Comment: Sorry just updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyk2P/1/ I was missing the overflow: hidden; in the .nofloat element

Comment: Now I get case #2 on both Chrome 27 PC and iPhone

Comment: I dont get case#2 on Chrome 28 PC but case#1. I do get case#2 on iPhone. Can you double check, please? Remember : case#1 = no margin between the two blocks, case#2 = margin visible

Comment: This is how I see in Chrome: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0af1lcv0f0

Comment: Thanks. That is, indeed, case#1 and not case#2 : you have no margin between the two blocks. Check on iPhone, there will be a margin. I updated the image in my main post to make it more accurate now about how the margin is actually treated. My previous drawing might have confused you because it was representing the full content under the floated where as technically, the content is limited by overflow:hidden and therefore the margin applied just after. Anyway : the problem with the margin stays exactly the same. Thank your for your patience

Comment: No problem. Here is a preview on iPhone: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=e1e6787

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35175/discussion-between-angelin-and-barakadam)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to CSS2.1 spec, this is a situation with undefined exact behavior. Since the `.nofloat` block has `overflow:hidden`, it establishes the new block formatting context. The spec [says the following](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float) about this situation:

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an
>   element in the normal flow that establishes a [new block formatting
>   context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting) (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible')
>   must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block
>   formatting context as the element itself. If necessary,
>   implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any
>   preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is
>   sufficient space. They may even make the border box of said element
>   narrower than defined by [section 10.3.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth). CSS2 *does not define*
>   when a UA may put said element next to the float or *by how much said
>   element may become narrower*.

So I believe this is normal. Both behaviors don't contradict the spec. While desktop and tablet browsers tend to use as much horizontal space as available, mobile browsers tend to make text blocks narrower in order to make it easier to read them on small screens. I believe that there is nothing to 'fix' in this behavior, but if you need more consistent display, you can use other layout models (e.g. `display: table-*` or Flexbox) instead of floats.

Comment: Bounty for such a clear answer. You are right. This confirms I should not insist in using overflow:hidden to force a "column-like" behaviour. This was used in a WordPress themes with shortcodes and the idea was to have CSS rules to create mini-layouts with the most concise CSS. This trick was very handy, but you are right, the spec leaves a hole opened for interpretation. So I will control this aspect differently. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different CSS rules depending on the size of  the view. Sounds like the systems have different methods of rending the CSS so you might have to be more specifc with these:

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-device-adapt/#viewport-descriptors

Comment: Thanks, but this is not a problem related to the size of the viewport, but to the way the CSS are interpreted. Actually, the problem also occurs on GalaxyTab tablets.

Comment: Using these you can specify the CSS you need to get the results wanted

Comment: No, you cannot, because you would have to target multiple devices with multiple viewports and GalaxyTab is as bis as a PC screen. This would be like using "hacks" when it is a pure CSS interpretation problem. Media queries are not appropriate here.